# What if the lambda function does not have any argument in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, arguments

I recently read a line of code and do not understand what is it meaning, the code is

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(lambda : [-1, -1, -1])
```

I'm confused about the `lambda` here. I only know `lamnda x: x+1`. Usually, we have an argument for `lambda`. What if we don't have argument like this code?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can define a lambda function without any argument. But, it will be useless because there will be nothing to operate on. Let’s have a look at a simple example.

```
get_5 = lambda: 5

print(get_5())  # 5
```

Since the lambda function is always returning the same value, we can just assign it a variable. Using lambda function without any argument is plain abuse of this feature.

---

```
d = collections.defaultdict([-1, -1, -1])
```

produces the error:

```
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None
```

since list isin't callable, but lambda functions are callable.

Answer (score 3):

Lambda function can be used efficiently even without the lambda variable in python.
General procedure for usage of lambda function is as  given

### in case of general function usage is

```
def identity(x):
    return x+1
```

### in case of lambda

```
lambda x:x+1
```

### no variable

```
lambda :x
```

will return same as `x`.

Without a variable the lambda function stays idle without any action an hence it can be used without a variable for getting the same answer.
In precise usage of lambda without a variable of action is just an extra line of code.But it is valid.